# SQL View/Query to return sum by current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum

Sorry for such a newbie question but I am that a newbie.

```
SELECT     SUM([Sales Total]) AS Sales, Salesperson, Date
FROM         dbo.[Sales by Salesperson]
GROUP BY Date, Salesperson
```

Trying to return only the SUM of Sales by Salesperson by current month.

```
Example:
Jaime Smith   | 1,000,000
John Doe      | 1,200,000
```

I have the data pulling for the Salesperson but don't know how to show only the current month.

Comment: Your DB is SQL Server? Just want to confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT SUM([Sales Total]) AS Sales,
    Salesperson,
    YEAR(Date) [Year],
    MONTH(Date) [Month]
FROM dbo.[Sales by Salesperson]
WHERE YEAR(Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) /*To filter by month*/
GROUP BY Salesperson, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SUM([Sales Total]) AS Sales, Salesperson, Date
FROM dbo.[Sales by Salesperson]
where year(date) = year(getdate())
and month(date) = month(getdate())
GROUP BY Date, Salesperson
```

Comment: Grouping by date will divide the result by the day part too and so will not work.

Comment: Oh Yes, you are right. should be group by year(date), month(date)